# How to pass data to bootstrap modal dialog in Angular2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to show up a dialog in an Angular 2 application. I am using the below code for that. I am able to open up the dialog and now I need to pass the data to the dialog, how can I do that ?? I tried writting JQuery code to do that but JQuery code doesnt work for me in the angular2 application.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply define data in the class and bind in the interpolation syntax of angular `{{ }}` , No need to use extra JQuery like this :-

```
Header: string = 'Angular2+Bootstrap Modal';
Text: string = "Description Here....";
```

and used in HTML like this:-

```
{{Text}} and {{Header}}
```

<kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GhnCHy3jUKB6LLZDlhrp?p=preview)</kbd>

Alternatively if you want to use this modal as component and want to pass data than you can use `Eventemitter`
here is example <kbd>[Working Example With Eventemitter](http://plnkr.co/edit/AiDiNl8SrSKIwDUYWl50?p=preview)</kbd>

## Update  - Setting Dynamic value in the modal

To Send data dynamically to the modal you have to create one component for the bootstrap modal.
than by using `@Input()` you are able to set dynamic value in the modal like this :-

```
 @Input() header :any;

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">
            <a *ngFor='#Number of data'>
                {{Number.id}} &nbsp; &nbsp; {{Number.label}} &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <delete [header]="Number.label" [pk]='Number.id'></delete><br>
            </a>
        </div>
```

<kbd>[Working Demo of Setting Dynamic Value in Modal](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wBnEHOS5zNGXNhg9Tzy)</kbd>

## update2 HTTP request

you have to make http request in the `ngOnInit` hook of angular, you already got you dynamical data than you can do manipulation as you want :-

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.header);   // here is the value that you passed dynamically

    this.http.get('app/cities.json')    // making http request here 
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res, "Subscribe Response"))
  }
```

<kbd>[Working Example With HTTP request](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wBnEHOS5zNGXNhg9Tzy?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Pardeep, this will work fine if you have static data. But in my case the data that needs to be sent to the the modal dialog is dynamic, what I have is that I have a label, and in front of every label there is a button and on click on that button, I need to send the value of label to my modal dialog.

Comment: thanks pardeep, can you please share the code on your plunkr link.

Comment: thanks, pardeep, I could see the code that is there in plunker

Comment: pardeep, I need your help again buddy. I got my dynamic value that I pass to my modal component. My requirement is that by using this value that I have passed, I have to make a GET request. For that, I will have to come back to my class section in my component. When I click on the button, my modal div in my HTML file gets displayed but how to come to my class section of my component to invoke a service from there. In-fact I need to take the input that I have passed, call a service first and then display my modal dialog with the data that I got from my service.

Comment: yeah sure buddy, but i did't get you, what exactly you want to do please update your question may clear something more for me.

Comment: When I click on the button on my base component ,I need to take the input that I have passed, call a web-service and then display my modal dialog with the data that I got from my service. Does this make it clear ??

Comment: @sunnyarya check my second update, hope this clears everything that you want.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to use jquery to show data in Angular.

You could do something like this.

```
@Component({
  template:`<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modal.header}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{modal.text}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>`
})

export class ComponentThatUSESMODAL{
   public modal = {
    "header":"MODAL HEADER",
    "text" : "MODAL TEXT"
   };
   constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: Gunter, this will work fine if you have static data. But in my case the data that needs to be sent to the the modal dialog is dynamic, what I have is that I have a label, and in front of every label there is a button and on click on that button, I need to send the value of label to my modal dialog